# Apache Beam Session Window with limit on number of events

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing, windowing

We have a requirement to generate user sessions when there is no activity for 10 minutes for a user but with the following tweaks

- we also want to end the session when number of events in the session reaches 20k
- end the session after 4 hours from the first event in the window

For 10 minute session window - we have done the below which is working:

```
'User Session Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(10 * 60),                                                    
                        timestamp_combiner=window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EOW)
```

I need to know how we can add the other two conditions - so that if any of the condition succeeds - we want to emit the rows

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can write a custom [WindowFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.31.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/window.py#L119) based on the existing [Sessions](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.31.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/window.py#L537) that uses a [BoundedWindow](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.31.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/window.py#L200) that tracks element count to track these extra constraints. Note that this will increase the non-determinism of your pipeline, as the exact set of windows emitted will be sensitive to the order in which elements appear. For example

```
class CountingIntervalWindow(BoundedWindow):
  def __init__(self, start, end, count):
    ...

class BoundedSessions(WindowFn):
  def assign(self, context):
    # type: (WindowFn.AssignContext) -> List[CountingIntervalWindow]
    timestamp = context.timestamp
    return [CountingIntervalWindow(timestamp, timestamp + self.gap_size, 1)]

  def get_window_coder(self):
    return PickleCoder()

  def merge(self, merge_context):
    # type: (WindowFn.MergeContext) -> None
    end = MIN_TIMESTAMP
    to_merge = []
    running_count = 0
    for w in sorted(merge_context.windows, key=lambda w: w.start):
      if to_merge:
        if (# Overlap
            end > w.start
            # Not too many elements.
            and running_count < self.count_limit
            # Not too large
            and w.end - to_merge[0].start < self.time_limit):
          to_merge.append(w)
          running_count += w.count
          if w.end > end:
            end = w.end
        else:
          if len(to_merge) > 1:
            merge_context.merge(
                to_merge,
                CountingIntervalWindow(to_merge[0].start, end, running_count))
          to_merge = [w]
          end = w.end
          running_count = w.count
      else:
        to_merge = [w]
        end = w.end
        running_count = w.count
    if len(to_merge) > 1:
      merge_context.merge(
          to_merge,
          CountingIntervalWindow(to_merge[0].start, end, running_count))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @robertwb. I tried this, but didn't get expected result. Mostly I think because "w.end - to_merge[0].start < self.time_limit" this condition would never be True since w.end keeps on progressing forward. 

Also - wanted to just confirm if we need to use multiple triggers for this or the DefaultTrigger should be enough since all the windowing logic is handled in the above?

Comment: With the solution you proposed, it is getting triggered only on session window timeout - not on any other of the 2 conditions

Comment: `w.end` should keep progressing forward until the `w.end - to_merge[0].start < self.time_limit` is no longer true, which would cause it to fall into the else clause and start a new window.

Comment: What runner are you running on?

Comment: I am testing this on directrunner. and on production we run it on dataflow gcp